# Intel NIC teaming or server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, nic, bonding

I'd like to implement NIC teaming on one of my servers and would like to know if it's better to use the Intel NIC teaming from the drivers or to use the NIC teaming from Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely windows server 2012 teaming. Remember if your objective is to maximize throughput you should use LACP, this implies that you have also to configure your switch to accept LACP negotiation. 
Else if you prefer "switch indipendent teaming" the server will use both nic in send direction but, in recive direction, the server will use only one nic the other will be just failover.

If you want more, and you like to go deep:
http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=13984